# UIPopoverController strange resize behavior

Tags: ios, ipad, uipopovercontroller, window-resize

I developed a static library for iPhone using a UINavigationController & pushing some UIViewControllers.

I'm implementing a way to permit ipad developers to include my library to their iPad applications. To do so, I want to display my library controllers in a UIPopoverController whose size is the iphone one.

That's I have developed, but each time i'm pushing a new viewController, the Popover resizes itself a very strange way:

[image]

I've checked my view controllers (via interface builder), and the AutoResize behaviors are deactivated.

Anybody have a solution ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `UIViewController` that the `UIPopoverViewController` displays needs to set this property:

```
contentSizeForViewInPopover
```

to indicate its displaying size, and the `UIPopoverViewController` will get resized according to the value of that property. For example:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.contentSizeForViewInPopover = self.view.frame.size;
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view from its nib.
}
```

Comment: Thank's, I didn't know it was so easy !

Comment: As of iOS7 and higher, this property is deprecated. Use preferredContentSize instead.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand your problem, the popover resizes whenever you push a controller to the `UINavigationController`, which is the root controller of your `UIPopoverController`. I cannot say why this happens but you can get rid of it by sending a reference of your popoverController (`popoverControllerReference`, you can create a singleton reference) to your view controller and manually setting the `popoverContentSize` whenever you push controllers: `popoverControllerReference.popoverContentSize = CGSizeMake(320, 460);`

Comment: Yes, I tried that but even if I called manually `popoverContentSize` in wiewWillAppear method, it was always before the UIVewController called it itself with the wrong size.

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer uses a method that is now deprecated in iOS 7.0.

I was having the same issue and had success using popoverContentSize.

Something along this below:

```
[_popoverSegue.popoverController setPopoverContentSize:CGSizeMake(320.0f, 460.0f)];
```

where _popoverSegue is an instance of UIStoryboardPopoverSegue

Hope this helps future visitors...

(sorry I should've probably commented to accepted answer but I don't have enough reputation...)